# Problem with css top property while creating a A4 PDF with HTML2PDF

Tags: php, jquery, css, html2pdf

**This is my case:**

I have a page where my users can create a template for a PDF file. The user can add a background and add text boxes. It has a preview at the side that is 1/5 of an A4 paper (701x496 pixels).

When the user save the template, I store in the DB the background, the text boxes content and the top relative position and left relative position of each text box.

The problem starts when I use that info to generate the PDF file.
I'm using html2pdf from spipu. I managed to make it add all boxes and the background to the PDF. The problem is the boxes position that isn't going in the same position of the preview on the previous page. I'm using this code to calculate the position and size of the boxes:

```
$box->top = number_format((($box->top) / 701) * 100,2,".","");
$box->left = number_format((($box->left) / 496) * 100,2,".","");
$box->width = number_format((($box->width) / 496) * 100 ,2,".","");
$box->height = number_format((($box->height) / 701) * 100,2,".","");
```

I'm calculating the position as a % of the preview page.
For example, this is the result of the preview page and the generated PDF:
[Preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLg2i.png) [Generated PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKXzW.png)

(In that images, ignore the position of the text, just see the border of the boxes)

For some reason the middle box is going in the correct position and the boxes near the margin of the page aren't.

Any help are truly welcome. I'm stuck at this for too many days.

Edit:
This is the HTML code that is being used to generate the PDF:

```
<style>
p, span {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
div {
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
<page style="font-size: 18px" backimg="files/fundos/img_4144917225d2dd82d1ab1f6.40072501.png" backimgx="left" backimgy="top" backimgw="100%" backtop="0" backbottom="0">
<div style="display:inline-block;border:1px dashed #000;margin:0;position:absolute;top:9.84%;left:23.59%;width:52.42%;height:8.42%;">
<p style="text-align:center;"><span style="color:#c0392b;"><span style="font-size:57.6px;"><strong>PROMOÇÃO</strong></span></span></p>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;border:1px dashed #000;margin:0;position:absolute;top:34.95%;left:9.88%;width:79.44%;height:18.26%;">
<p style="text-align:center;"><span style="font-family:Devonshire;"><span style="font-size:76.8px;">!col1!</span></span></p>
<p style="text-align:center;"> </p>
<p style="text-align:center;"> </p>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;border:1px dashed #000;margin:0;position:absolute;top:58.06%;left:18.15%;width:63.10%;height:12.41%;">
<p style="text-align:center;"><span style="font-family:Lobster;"><span style="font-size:115.2px;">!col2</span></span></p>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;border:1px dashed #000;margin:0;position:absolute;top:79.74%;left:9.68%;width:66.33%;height:8.27%;">
<p><span style="color:#e74c3c;"><span style="font-family:'komika_handregular';"><span style="font-size:41.6px;">!col3!</span></span></span></p>
<p style="text-align:center;"> </p>
</div>
</page>
```

Comment: Looking at the docs for the HTML2PDF, the HTML needs to be formatted in a particular way.. What is the HTML that is being sent into the conversion process?

Comment: @Ryan edited the question with the code.

Comment: Having used FPDF/TCPDF extensively in the past, I would strongly consider using those libraries directly as you will have more control over the positioning of elements. Thought that would depend on your application to whether it's feasible..

Comment: @RaphaelM You can also check Wkhtmltopdf which convert lots of html property to pdf. https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html